# Facebook Api Comments count issue

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have issue with facebook api,i am getting facebook page posts, likes count is ok but comment count is not giving permission

my code is:

```
$permissions = ['email', 'user_posts', 'pages_show_list', 'pages_manage_engagement', 'pages_read_user_content', 'pages_read_engagement', 'page_post_engagements'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count, add ?summary=1 at the end: https://graph.facebook.com/125909647492772_502974003098530/comments?summary=1

Comment: i am using same link but permission issue always occure

Comment: "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "AzE2mkG-BRngHkvgAImU844"
   }

Comment: Please look at this https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/post-id?fields=insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total).period(lifetime).as(post_reactions_by_type_total),comments.summary(true).limit(0),insights.metric(post_clicks_by_type).period(lifetime),shares&access_token=XXX